Backing up my entire Windows OS and then booting from restored backup
Have just been coming up with a new backup strategy for my Windows systems, as previously i would use the Windows System Image tool very occasionally, however this is quite clunky, and i have heard it doesn't always do the best job of restoring a system.
Installed Aomei to try out, seems alright, however i really don't quite understand what i am doing, would like some guidance.
My Objective: Backup everything on my drive to an image (NOT a clone, since i want to be able to store images of multiple systems on my large external USB HDD, and i want to use Aomei's incremental backups.), including everything needed for Windows to boot. The idea being if my drive fails, all i have to do is buy a new one, image it from the backup, and boot right back into my OS again. No hassle of setting up a fresh installation, installing new programs, etc.
What I have tried: My laptop has 1 SSD, with 4 partitions. The EFI System Partition, the Windows partition (C:), and two recovery partitions. As seen here:

I thought that if I backed up the Windows partition and the EFI system partition, i would be good to go in terms of restoring to a new drive, and booting up. As I understand, the two recovery partitions are irrelevant in this situation?
Within Aomei, I selected the 'Partition Backup' option, and then selected the EFI & Windows partitions. At this point, Aomei asked me if i wanted to use the 'System Backup' option, to preserve everything needed to boot - i declined, thinking i could achieve the same thing 'manually' with a Partition Backup, with finer control - For example, on my server PC, i want to exclude a particular partition from the backup.
After creating the backup, i restored it to an empty external HDD to test. First, i restored the EFI partition to the drive, with Aomei. I noticed once this completed, the partition was not marked as 'EFI System Partition' though. I followed the steps here to mark it as an EFI partition with Diskpart. I then restored the 'Windows' partition too. However, when i tried to boot my laptop from this HDD, imaged with the backup, i got the following error:

Interestingly, re-attaching the USB HDD i was trying to boot from to my system (Running from my original SSD), the HDD now looks like this:

The 260MB partition is no longer marked as an EFI partition, despite my efforts with Diskpart. Could this be the issue?
Sorry about the long post, would really appreciate some guidance: I don't quite understand how EFI partitions work and what i actually need to backup to be able to restore fully...
EDIT:
Thanks all for the information. I have done an Aomei 'Disk Backup' to backup my entire SSD, and then restored this to an old HDD to try out. It did boot up, and the system (mostly) worked OK. (Although this procedure removed the 'Windows Boot Manager' entry from my UEFI when i tried to boot into my SSD again, which was a pain. No idea why this happened?)
One thing to note is that on the HDD i restored to, the two recovery partitions were not marked as recovery partitions, but were rather blank, as seen here:

Not sure if this could cause trouble? (I am not too worried about recovery partitions though, because i am backing up my whole system...)
Although the information regarding DISM is helpful, i am not so focused on a 'native' way to image Windows, a 3rd party tool is in some ways better for me (I.E can image a running system).

You need to perform full disk images of your system disk if you want the ability to restore the image to a new disk and boot to it.  When you test the image, after you restore the image, disconnect the original disk. A proper image of the disk will only involve one step, restoring the image and connecting it to the system, you shouldn't trust any other process.

You'd capture a WIM of the OS partition from WinPE/WinRE (Step #1), then apply that WIM to a partition in order to boot to it (Step #2). To configure a new drive, see Steps 1 - 6 at the very bottom of the answer. It's not recommended to use Windows Image Backup or Backup and Restore (Windows 7), covering why under section Is the native method generally the best method for most users?

Recovery partitions (WinRE and an OEM one that can be deleted) weren't correctly created. The reason why capturing/applying a WIM is recommended is covered within the comprehensive answer linked to, specifically within section What are the pros and cons of native versus 3rd party?. How many days has been spent trying to correctly image the OS with 3rd party software and deal with the config problems? With an SSD, capturing a WIM takes a couple hours at most with max compression, whereas with an HDD, boot to WinPE/WinRE before bed, capture a WIM, and it'll be done by the time you wake up

(Cont'd...) The linked to answer covers why software that uses VSS to image the OS partition while booted to Windows isn't recommended within section Is the native method generally the best method for most users? Often a VHD is created as a base image with differential backups (which is what System Restore [rstrui] does) used to capture changes after the initial base image. I'm unsure what AOMEI uses, but it's likely a VHD, unless they initially capture a VHD, then WIM the VHD to get the benefits of WIMs (VHDs are not efficient backup mediums, whereas WIMs are - see section above)

There's no right or wrong way to image Windows, merely pros and cons to different methods. WIMs are recommend because they save time and are what Windows has been built upon since at least WinXP - Windows is installed from an install.<esd|wim>, WinPE/WinRE are contained within, and boots from, a boot.wim/winre.wim, Windows is deployed to tens, hundreds, and thousands of machines via WIMs using an LTI/ZTI, etc. Whether the inconvenience of booting to WinRE to capture a WIM is offset by WIM's benefits is determined by each user's pros/cons analysis

You need to use AOMEI Backupper to take a disk image and to create
the AOMEI boot media to restore it if the disk is destroyed:

The disk image is created by selecting "Backup" on the left panel
and choosing "Disk Backup" to back up the entire hard disk to an image file
on an external disk.
Create AOMEI Bootable CD/DVD/USB Based on Windows PE
As a partial test, boot the AOMEI bootable media and ensure that it can
see your backup (do not do the restore operation).

